# Google apps script HTML service and jQuery

Tags: jquery, google-apps-script

I am using GAS HTML service to create the interface and tried Javascript to handle client-side operations.

Is "this" not supported in HTML service and Caja?

In my HTML file I have this:

```
<input type="button" name="RemoveSample_1" id="RemoveSample_1" value="Remove" onClick="removeSampleNow(this)" />
```

and a simple Javascript function to test:

```
<script>
  function removeSampleNow(thisObj) {

    alert(thisObj.id);

  }
</script>
```

It works running the html locally on my desktop BUT NOT when it's ran in GAS.  Error is "undefined".

Can we not pass parameters to a function call?  How do we drive HTML element manipulations based on a selected/clicked button then?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the on click property in the html portion.  See the [Caja](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/html_service#Caja) restrictions.

See "Dynamically adding scripts or external CSS" for an example Of how to do it.

```
<script>
function doSomething() { alert('but this is fine!'); }
document.write('<input type="button" id="button1">')
document.getElementById('button1').onclick = doSomething;
</script>
```

Answer (score 6):

I disagree with @mzimmerman, you can use the onclick html property (though Caja will manipulate it). In the callback function you access the element via an argument, not 'this'.

There are two ways I know work. The first is the simplest. In the callback function the element will be the argument, not 'this'.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function onClickCallback(element){
        console.log('element.id ' + element.id);
        element.value = 'Clicked!';
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <input type="button" name="b1" id="b1" value="Click me" onclick='onClickCallback(this)' />
  </body>
</html>
```

The second way uses the power of JQuery to bind the callback function dynamically at run time, and in this case, the callback function does access the element via 'this' (and there is no need for an argument to the function). Whilst this second example isn't necessary (the first solution will work fine) I'm including it because you will find a library such as JQuery offers you so much.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      // like onload but doesn't wait for images, only the dom
      $(document).ready(function() {
        // bind the click handler at run time
        $('#b1').click(onClickCallback);
      });

      function onClickCallback(){
        console.log('this.id ' + this.id);
        this.value = 'Clicked!';
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <input type="button" name="b1" id="b1" value="Click me" />
  </body>
</html>
```